# p4 will not register my file changes when I sync

Tags: git, perforce

When I sync remote repo changes to perforce, one of the files I changed does not register in pending changes. I went to the correct directory in which to run my sync from the terminal and ran this command: ./p4sync-groups.sh   , using the correct credentials in each of the arguments listed. Additionally, I run this command in the master branch so that I am not accidentally trying to sync a feature/bugfix branch, etc. When I go back to p4 and click refresh after the sync succeeds, I see a whole list of pending changes that are correct. Yet, one of the files that has been updated in remote repository does not list as a changed file. Additionally, for clarification, I ran a git fetch and a git rebase before I ran the sync command, so I have all of the latest code to sync. I don't understand why a file that was clearly changed is not listing as changed. Every step seems correct to me. Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - all I had to do was stop all terminal processes and restart p4. Then I had to run another git fetch from master and THEN run the script.